# how to delete a file using racket code?

Tags: racket

I want to delete a file using racket. I am using following code.

```
 (delete-file c://foo.txt)
```

I am getting this message.

```
reference to an identifier before its definition:
c://foo.txt
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Lisp-like languages, but isn't your path supposed to be a string ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(delete-file "c:/foo.txt")
```

BTW, since you're asking very basic questions, perhaps it's better to read [the guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/) first?